# Paypal sandbox transaction id is not equal in payer and payee account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

[image]Hello I have implemented smart button integration in my angular application and made the one time payment successfully using ngx paypal library. I am stuck in verifying the transaction in both payer and payee sandbox account are not the same, will both will be different or same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all PayPal transactions, the Transaction ID in the sender and receiver accounts will be different.

Each account has its own Transaction ID.

Comment: Thank you How do I get both the transaction details while payment

Comment: You don't. You only receive the transaction ID for the account that belongs to you.  Use the invoice ID field to store your own identifier.

Comment: Do u mean order ID Correct me if I am wrong, but when I have cross-checked with api.sandbox.com/orders/{orderid} API gives me the Transaction ID of the Payee account

Comment: No, I do not mean that. The order ID is only used during payment creation and approval. It is not important, and it is not a transaction ID.

Comment: ok what is the difference between data.id in OnApprove and data.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id in OnAuthorize callbacks

Comment: One is an order ID which is only used during checkout and payment approval.  The other is a capture or transaction ID and of actual accounting importance.   Also you are talking about things in different sdks

Comment: ok How to get invoice id after the transaction completes

Comment: It will be in the payment capture details

Comment: I have included my completed transaction complete JSON  please which ID id need to send Database if you send the snippet would help me a lot

Comment: payments -> captures -> 0 -> id

Comment: you said that is transaction ID a minute ago previously, Now you are saying it is Invoice that's what confuses me, if I am cleared I will move further

Comment: Yes, that is the seller/payee transaction id. That is what is important to store. If you want a unique identifier to show up in both the seller/payee and buyer accounts, you need to create and pass such a value yourself in the purchase_units -> invoice_id field, and it must be unique for every completed transaction. If you pass such a value, you will get it back in the capture's purchase_unit array.

Comment: Thank you for the idea Kindly post me the sample invoce_id value which you say that I have to pass on create

Comment: Come up with each transaction's invoice_id yourself. It's basically your own system's unique order ID.  If you have multiple websites, add a prefix.

Comment: Thank you @Preston PHX I got the invoice Id by sending purchase_units to create a payment, How do I get the buyer transaction id after payment complete

Comment: The buyer can see the buyer transaction ID in their own account. If you aren't the buyer, you don't get it.